# How to fix date time format in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have a data Frame df**
[image]
so i converted it to date time using pandas,
`stock_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(stock_data['Date'],unit='s')`

[image]

**but when i'm plotting this, i get this....**
[image]

I think this is not a right format for date and time so, i tried converting this to time stamp.

`df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date).asi8`
but then also no luck
how do i fix this?

Comment: You need to show the line where you imported the dataframe (`df`). I suspect that is where your date/time parsing is happening with `pandas`.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, can you please check the question i've added the initial steps

Comment: Did you try this `plt.scatter(df['Date'], df["C"], marker = "^", color = "green", label = "Close Price");`?

Comment: @yashaswavarshney answered you. What in buy, show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there are two solutions.

1.I downloaded the data from yfinance and specifically reset the indexes to turn the 'Datetime' indexes into a column. And I draw a scatter, specifying a list of indexes. Possible that you have these indexes and have buy?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download(tickers='AAPL', period="3d", interval="15m")
df = df.reset_index()

plt.scatter(df['Datetime'].values[[7, 55, 70]], df['Close'].values[[7, 55, 70]], color='magenta')
plt.plot(df['Datetime'].values, df['Close'].values)
plt.legend(['stock', 'point'])
plt.show()
```

2.And also try to specify indexes in plt.plot, when drawing line, something like this:

```
plt.plot(df['C'].index, df['C'])
```

Perhaps because of this, such a picture turns out that the scatter appears somewhere at the beginning of the indexes.